# Pattern searching python function does not give expected result

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote a function, which returns the value to the main code only when the input is given in the correct format, to add in my school project but I am facing a small problem and I can't understand the reason why.

This is the code -

```
def xinput(text, pattern):
    myinput = input(text)
    match = re.search(pattern,myinput)
    if match is None:
        print("\nError. \nPlease give input in correct format.\n")
        xinput(text, pattern)
    else:
        return myinput


val = xinput("Enter a number : ", pattern=r"^[\d]+$")
print(val)
```

Entering the correct value the first time works but if a wrong input is given the first time and the correct input the second time, it returns None.

Here is the output -

```
Enter a number : q

Error. 

Please give input in correct format.

Enter a number : 1
None
```

I've checked it and `myinput` remains `1` till just before returning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the value returned by your recursive calls:

```
if match is None:
    print("\nError. \nPlease give input in correct format.\n")
    return xinput(text, pattern) # added return here
else:
    return myinput
```

Since you don't return it in your code, when your function completes it comes inside your if statement and does nothing with the result hence returns `None`.